# Segmentation fault using basic SSE instructions

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, sse, intrinsics

I just started working with SSE instructions:
The program reads two matrices into a contiguous buffer, and then try to operate with them from there, here is the code:

```
void multMatrix(void * buffer,int n){
    int i,j;
    float *p = (float*) buffer;
    float *q = (float*) buffer + (n*n);
    float mr[n][n];

    __m128 va = _mm_load_ps(&p[0]);
    __m128 vb = _mm_load_ps(&q[0]);
    __m128 mm_r = _mm_add_ps( va, vb );
    _mm_store_ps (mr[0],mm_r);

    return;
}
```

Buffer is defined as:

```
void * buffer = malloc(sizeof(float)*n*n*2 + sizeof(float));
```

I'm getting seg. fault at this line: `__m128 mm_r = _mm_add_ps( va, vb );`

but if I comment `_mm_store_ps (mr[0],mm_r);` it exits normally.

I'm just testing and learning SSE instructions, but my goal for this program is to make:

```
A[n][n] * B[n][n] = C[n][n]
```

Comment: SSE arrays needs to be aligned on specific boundaries. The `malloc` might not use proper alignment. Neither does defining arrays. You need to use either platform- or compiler-specific functions to allocate with suitable alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try using unaligned loads and stores: loadu, storeu. Then make the buffers / pointers aligned to 16-byte boundaries.

Also the pointer q accesses the matrix out of range — when the last store instruction is commented out, the compiler is probably smart enough not to produce any of those instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I managed to make it work simply by changing all the mallocs to _mm_mallocs aligning al the arrays to 16 bytes. I was having some difficulty grasping the concept of aligned, but its all clear now.